# OTP base Authentication

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-web-api2, sha256, one-time-password

I would like to implement OTP based authentication for my Web API application. I have some idea on the OTP authentication. 
For OTP we have generate an random alphanumeric, I have store this in my db. And send this OTP to user mobile phone. User will submit this OTP and mach this OTP with db.
This is the normal flow.
I need to secure it more, Hows it possible. Means, need to hash the OTP by sha256. Then I want to store this hashed value in DB. Upto here it's fine. 
From next step, Shall I send this OTP as plain text to user mobile. Then mobile client application pass this OTP as a plain text, Hash this plain text OTP in server and compared this with DB? 
Is it correct, Or Instead of plain text, Does I want to pass OTP as a hash to the user phone number, Is it so, Is it secured.
I have confused about this little bit.

Please help me.

Comment: You have misunderstood the concept of OTP. What you describe looks like just a second password, not a one time password system.

Comment: @Kuhmonen Exactly I think so. Could you please shed some light.

Comment: I suggest reading https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6238 and https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4226

Comment: just use a 3rd party services like google authentication. if you want to integrate SMS, use the twilio service. if you try building it from scratch, odds are you will screw up and leave yourself more vulnerable.